# Auto-populate Form Field Based on Selection

Tags: formatting

I need to be able to type in an invoice number into a form field and have the remainder of the information populate into the form. Can anyone provide me with any code or references on how to do this? Thanks!

Comment: Where is the related information to be pulled from?

Comment: We would be pulling data from a SQL server.